# EF Core getting part of a string in a call

Tags: c#

I've set up a generic repository and pull data back from my database. Part of my data includes file upload information including the location where the file is stored ala:

`\\RemoteLocation\Desktop\TargetFolder\MyFile.csv`

What I want is to remove all of the parts before `MyFile.csv` but I'm struggling to do so. Currently I'm using `LINQ` to gather the parts of the data I need like so:

```
var fileData = _files.GetAll(); 
var latestFile = fileData.Where(x => x.FileLoadedTime != null && x.LoadStatusId == 4 && x.EngineId == 1).ToList().Last(); // most recent is at the bottom of the list
```

Could someone please show me how I can chop off the parts of my data that I don't need?

Comment: If I understand it correctly then you want file name instead of entire path? is that correct?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Yes. That is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking for is `Path.GetFileName(yourPath)`

I am assuming your file class is like the following

```
public class File{
    public DateTime FileLoadedTime;
    public int LoadStatusId;
    public int EngineId;
    public string Path;
}

var fileData = _files.GetAll(); 
var latestFile = fileData.Where(x => x.FileLoadedTime != null && x.LoadStatusId == 4 
                 && x.EngineId == 1).ToList().Last(); // most recent is at the bottom of the list

var path = Path.GetFileName(latestFile.Path);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to get file name from path, you can try below

[Path.GetFileName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netcore-3.1)

```
    string result1 = Path.GetFileName(latestFile);
    Console.WriteLine(result1);
```

Or

Using [Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1):

```
    string result =  latestFile.Split('\\').Last();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bMjkQZ)